# EmberJS RC6 Router Catch All

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

The application that I am writing uses both EmberJS route (using #) and normal traditional HTML anchors. There are reasons for doing so and using normal anchor is not something that I can avoid at the moment.

I used to use the following line in my Router map.

this.route('catchAll', {path:"*:"});

The above used to work until I updated to RC6 and I start getting the "Uncaught Error: There is no route named ..."

Is there a new way to do catch all in the current version of Ember?

Comment: Confirming that the `path: *:` solution posted by @Daniel works for me in RC.6 as well. Perhaps some other related issue may be involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that if your hashes do not begin with a '/' they will not work any more. I would say that this is a bug in the rc6 router.

Comment: This seems to be the case, all of the anchor will need to be preceded by slash. So instead of saying index.php#goToAnchor, I will have to say index.php#/goToAnchor

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me as if it's still working.  Would you mind showing me a jsfiddle with it not working?

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('catchAll', { path: '*:' });
  this.route('place', {path: '/place'});
});
```

[jsfiddle of it working on RC6](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZpDu/)

Is it possibly failing somewhere else?  Is it failing on a programmatic transitionTo instead of a href change?  If so, it probably has to do with the new router pushed in by machty and we should probably submit a bug.

Comment: It seems that we have to use a slash in front of the anchor name now. I modified the fiddle and removed the slashes and I get the same error. http://jsfiddle.net/codingepiphany/9shqV/6/ I'm certain that this used to work in the past before RC6, therefore I was able to do a catch all.

Comment: Thanks. The colon in `{path: '*:'}` is quite important!